# Getting error when running this code in webscraping how can do please suggess

Tags: web-scraping, request

`requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '<Response [200]>': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://<Response [200]>?`

```
import requests
from requests.packages import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
import json

r = requests.get('https://cpcb.nic.in/cpcb-directions-5ep.php', verify=False)
headers = {
"authority": "https://cpcb.nic.in/index.php",
"scheme": "https",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Cookie": "style=light-blue; PHPSESSID=ir5chrghoud1lakake482eckt6",
"Host": "cpcb.nic.in",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
"Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
 Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"
}
response = requests.get(r, headers=headers)
file = response.content

try:
    new = file.decode('utf-8')
    for k in json.loads(new).get('Table'):
        print(k)

except:
    pass'''
```

Comment: You are feeding in the response of your first `requests.get()`, as your url in the second `requests.get()` Why are you doing 2 requests??

Answer (score 0):

You are finding in the response of your first `requests.get()`, as your url in the second `requests.get()`

Here's a different way. Use session to create a session and get the cookies. Then add that to your headers. Next you can do the request with the session. Then since you are after the table, just use pandas to parse that:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://cpcb.nic.in/cpcb-directions-5ep.php'

r = s.get(url, verify=False)

cookies = s.cookies.get_dict()
cookieStr = ''
for k, v in cookies.items():
    cookieStr += k +'=' + v +';'
headers = {
"authority": "https://cpcb.nic.in/index.php",
"scheme": "https",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Cookie": cookieStr,
"Host": "cpcb.nic.in",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
"Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"
}


response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.read_html(response.text)
print(df[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df[-1])
      S No.                 Subject  ... Date of Issue   Download
0         1  Sewage treatment Plant  ...    11-02-2021  617.61 KB
1         2           Plastic Waste  ...    05-02-2021  661.88 KB
2         3           Plastic Waste  ...    05-02-2021  233.00 KB
3         4           Plastic Waste  ...    05-02-2021  222.68 KB
4         5         Water Pollution  ...    05-02-2021  457.11 KB
    ...                     ...  ...           ...        ...
3456   3457       Online monitoring  ...    02-02-2017  955.97 KB
3457   3458       Online monitoring  ...    17-01-2017  824.70 KB
3458   3459       Online monitoring  ...    06-01-2017  127.15 KB
3459   3460       Online monitoring  ...    04-01-2017  885.06 KB
3460   3461       Online monitoring  ...    04-01-2017  896.72 KB

[3461 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: but Download pdf url not coming , how can i get pdf url also